# Why is my value being overwritten in this loop?

Tags: c#, loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < entity.files[temp].slides.Count(); i++){
    entity.files[temp].slides[i].versions[0] = Program.optionNode.Attributes["cloudfrontLocation"].Value + "/" + customer + "/" + fileName + "/Slide" + (i+1) + "_v1.PNG";
    Console.WriteLine("after loop " + i + " value is " + entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This results in these logs:

> after loop 0 value is
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net//xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/Slide1_v1.PNG
>
> after loop 1 value is
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net//xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/Slide2_v1.PNG
>
> after loop 2 value is
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net//xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/Slide2_v1.PNG

It's what it's supposed to be on the first loop, but I don't know why `slides[0].versions[0]` is changing on the second iteration, when it should be accessing `slides[1].versions[0]`. I'm also logging `i` so you can see that it changes.

Why is the value `entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]` changing on the second iteration of the loop?

Is there something wrong with my loop?

Comment: " value is " + entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]. You're always printing the index 0, not index i.

Comment: the increment of the index `i` doesn't affect this : `entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0])` at `slides`

Comment: @dutt I know. I'm doing this to show that `slides[0].versions[0]` is changing when I'm not intending for it to be changed

Comment: @lnanikian could you rephrase that? I don't know what you mean by this?

Comment: @Houseman your question is ambiguous

Comment: Because you are asking for `entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]`. You set this to a new slide every time here: `Program.optionNode.Attributes["cloudfrontLocation"].Value + "/" + customer + "/" + fileName + "/Slide" + (i+1) + "_v1.PNG"`

Comment: @logixologist you got the point

Comment: @logixologist @lnanikian I know I'm asking for `entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]`. I'm asking for that so that I can demonstrate that it changes when it's not supposed to be accessed. I'm iterating through `i`. `i` is not 0 every time, therefore, I'm not changing `slides[0]` every time. I'm changing `slides[i]`. `i` is only `0` once. I don't think you or Inanikian understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Can you provide an example that can reproduce it outside your environment?  Without know what `entity`, `files`, `slides`, and `versions` are, there is little we can do to diagnose it.

Comment: @Houseman Is another thread accessing the `slides[0].versions[0]` at the same time and changing it's value ? because it's the only possible answer

Comment: Maybe slides[0] and slides[1] and ... point to the same object? or versions in each slides are the same array?

Comment: @Selman22 I don't think so. I'm only receiving one set of console logs, so if another thread is accessing this, it's not running the same code.

Comment: I was thinking similar, @Gusman. Either that, or one of the property accessors has side-effects. "Step into" would be the way to find that.

Comment: @Gusman this could be possible. Let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the value `entity.files[temp].slides[0].versions[0]` changes **only** on the first and the second iteration of the loop, the `slides[0]` and `slides[1]` are pointing to the same object.

So, when the `slides[1]` is changing the `slides[0]` is changing also.